# How to get a list of matched ID's using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, asp.net-4.0

I am maintaining a dictionary of clients that are logged in with `_clientList.Add(clientIDGuid, newsfeedClient);`

NewsfeedClient class:

```
public class NewsfeedClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents Newsfeed's own clientID
    /// </summary>
    public string ClientIDGuid { get; set; }  // also adding the dictionary's ID

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the logged in client's session ID
    /// </summary>
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }

    public GeoLocation Location { get; set; }

    public List<MyDB.Models.Buddy> BuddyList { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public DateTime LastResponseTime { get; set; }

    public class GeoLocation
    {
        public float Latitude { get; set; }
        public float Longitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `Buddy` object contains a `ProfileID` property.

I want to get a list of all dictionary clientID's where the matching profileID is in the BuddyList of that new client.

I'm guessing that the Intersect method would come into play, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710341/linq-query-if-collection-contains-any-element-in-another-collection), but I'm not quite sure how to put this together without creating at least one `foreach` loop.

-- UPDATE --

The clientID is not == ProfileID these values are different.

Comment: So, to clarify - you want to find all the NewsFeedClient objects for all the ProfileId's contained in the BuddyList of a single NewsFeedClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming I've read your question correctly:

```
var matches = _clientList
            .Where(c => c.Value.BuddyList.Any(b => b.ProfileID == c.Value.ProfileID))
            .Select(c => c.Key)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to match the profileID to the dictionary key.  The dictionary key is just a GUID that won't match any profile ID's (int). So I want the dictionary key that contains a profileID that == Any of b.ProfileID.

Comment: Ah sorry, so you want to match the BuddyList Profile Id on the profileId in the newsFeedClient which is the Value item of the dictionary?

Comment: Right.  I thought I could iterate through a list of dictionary values, but would rather not have to start creating loops.  So I want the dictionary key where the value contains a profileID that is in the list of newsfeedClient.BuddyList.

Comment: Check my edit, that'll get you the Keys of the Dictionary where the BuddyList in the value contains the Profile ID for that Value, that right?

Comment: Ah yes, that looks better.  A bit of a doozy to explain.  Thanks.

Comment: Hehe no probs, glad I could help :)

Comment: Well, it looks right, but I finally got around to testing this morning, and matches is 0.  Working on another Linq issue this morning, and will revisit this.

Comment: That should return any client in the dictionary that has their ProfileId in their buddy list. Is this not what you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, I have your question correct, it should be like so:

```
var matches = _clientList.ToList()
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .Intersect(currentNewsFeed.BuddyList.Select(x => x.ProfileId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: There appear to be at least a ToList too many in your LINQ query (_clientList.ToList())

Comment: Yeah, doing _clientList.ToList() would break wouldn't it? as _clientList is currently a dictionary :)